# Datatables.net Excel export button is not displayed when using webpack

Tags: laravel, webpack, datatables, laravel-elixir, jszip

I'm using laravel 5.7 with elixir wrapper for webpack.

I added Datatables.net fine but Excel export button is not displayed.

This is my vendor.js

```
require('datatables.net');
require('datatables.net-bs4');
require('jszip');
require('datatables.net-buttons');
require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js');
require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js');
```

however the button Excel shows **fine** if I just add this to my html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js"></script>
```

I recon, `jszip` is not being required properly. What is a proper way?

No errors in js console.

`jszip` was downloaded fine into `node_modules`, like so

```
$ npm install jszip --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `vendor.js` is working fine:

```
require('datatables.net');
require('datatables.net-bs4');
window.JSZip = require('jszip');    
require('datatables.net-buttons');
require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js');
require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Bootstrap, you should use this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
buttons: [
    'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
] } );


table.buttons().container()
.appendTo( $('<#elementWhereYouNeddToShowThem>', table.table().container() ) );
```

Comment: the question was mostly about webpack, thank you for your answer